# Mousewheel causes drastic volume change

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

I may have discovered some kind of bug in the latest update for 14.04LTS. When I adjust the volume with the mouse wheel, the volume continues to rise or fall even if I only move it one click.

My volume control is impossible to set.  For some reason, when I adjust the volume just one notch of the mouse wheel turn, the volume slowly increases or decreases until the level is either too loud or too soft.  When I do manage to get it reasonably close, it tends to move back and forth with no explanation as to why.

If I move it just one notch, it gets intolerably loud, and then when I move it back, it gets low again.  and then it fluctuates a bit.

This just started three days ago, ironically when my friend bought a new laptop and we talked on Skype.  I blamed it on his computer until today when this occurred with multiple online videos.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, and so quickly, but rather than delete it, I thought it best to leave it up for the next person who has this problem.

I am using Vizio HDTVs for my monitors.  Somehow the audio setting for SRS True Volume got changed to "YES".

Changing it to "NO" fixed the problem.

While it turns out that this is NOT a Ubuntu problem, I hope it can help those others who may not realize the problem is in their TV.

Thank you for understanding.

Buck